# Json in VB.net version

Tags: vb.net, json

I have seen there are many examples in C# version. Same also as `DataContractJsonSerializer` class in MSDN. Anyone please help me on VB.net version?

Comment: Porting C# code to VB.NET is usually straightforward. A converter like this one http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/ does a good job. If you have any specific problem then edit your post with more details.

Comment: Indeed - or use "reflector", which can do (limited) translation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the same source code I have written in another question. It's a very simple piece of code that uses the library JAYROCK (you can download it free of charge here: http://jayrock.berlios.de/) that will read a JSON formatted string and will output the value of a parameter call "message" that is nested inside "error". Very basic stuff, but it might help you...

```
Dim cMessage As String = "{ ""error"" : { ""code"" : 500, " & _
                                """message"" : ""Error Executing Task. " & _
                                "Error executing tool.""," & _
                                """details"" : [] " & _
                                "}" & _
                                "}"

Dim objResponse As JsonObject


objResponse = CType(JsonConvert.Import(cMessage), JsonObject)

MsgBox( "Last response was: " + objResponse("error")("message") )
```

P.S.: In order to get this code working don't forget to import Jayrock.Json and Jayrock.Json.Conversion

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
            Dim ser As New DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(Product))
            Using fs As FileStream = File.OpenRead("c:\jsonText.txt")

                Dim product As Product = TryCast(ser.ReadObject(fs), Product)
                MessageBox.Show("Product Name: " & product.Name)
            End Using
        End Sub
    End Class

    <Serializable()> _
    Public Class Product
        Public Name As String
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Here is the vb.net sample taken from msdn and converted by developerfusion  converter